# multiple event which action is taking place

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do determine which action or event is taking place when you have the following code

```
$('#mydiv').on('click mousedown mousemove', function(event) { //<--multiple event
    if (action is mousedown) {

    }
    else if(action is mousemove){

    }
    else{
        //mouse click
    }
});
```

jsFiddle example welcomed.

Comment: Why don't you split it up into separate event handlers?

Comment: @SidharthMudgal with mouse clicks, you may need to perform specific actions with specific events that are al tied to each other. Like timing how long the mousedown event is happening, and performing an action based on when the mouseup event happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event.type` will get the event type as a string:

```
$('#mydiv').on('click mousedown mousemove', function(event) {
    switch(event.type) {
        case 'click':
                //do something on click
            break;
        case 'mousedown':
                //do something on mousedown
            break;
        case 'mousemove':
                //do something on mousemove 
            break;

       .....etc.
    }

});
```

You can also just do:

```
$('#mydiv').on(
   click: function() {
        //do something on click
   },
   mousedown: function() {
       //do something on mousedown
   },
   mousemove: function() {
      //do something on mousemove
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access which event it is with:

```
event.type
```

Your code can be written as:

```
$('#mydiv').on('click mousedown mousemove', function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'mousedown') {

    }
    else if (event.type == 'mousemove'){

    }
    else{
        //mouse click
    }
});
```

Reference: [event.type](http://api.jquery.com/event.type/)

Comment: Example: `if(event.type == 'mousedown'){ //do something }`

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the `event.type:`

```
$('#mydiv').on('click mousedown mousemove', function(event) { //<--multiple event
    console.log(event.type);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ra9r5/